# How to append and remove different divs with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, append

I made a checkbox to add and remove a div.

Now, **how do I do this?**: Have the first checkbox checked by default (so the first div is appended by default). Then, when checking the second checkbox, uncheck automatically the first checkbox. This should make the first div get removed and append the second div. (and viceversa)

This is my code, for reference

```js
            $(function(){
            let NewContent='<div class="added"> HELLO </div>'
            let added = false;
            let $content;
            $(".first").on('click', function(){
            if (!added) $content =  $(NewContent).appendTo('.toadd');
            else $content.remove();
            added = !added;
          });
        });


            $(function(){
            let NewContent='<div class="added"> BYE </div>'
            let added = false;
            let $content;
            $(".second").on('click', function(){
            if (!added) $content =  $(NewContent).appendTo('.toadd');
            else $content.remove();
            added = !added;
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toadd">
<label>One</label><input type="checkbox" class="first" />
<label>Two</label><input type="checkbox" class="second" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the checks to be exclusives... I suggest you use the normal behavior of [radio  buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) instead.

Then you just need to have a variable which will change from 0 to 1 at each click to choose from two content values in an array.

```js
$(function(){

  let content=[
    '<div class="added"> HELLO </div>',
    '<div class="added"> BYE </div>'
  ];
  let toggled=0;
    
$("[name='something']").on('change', function(){
    $(".added").remove();
    toggled=(toggled+1)%2;
    $(".toadd").append(content[toggled])
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toadd">
  <label>One</label><input type="radio" class="first" name="something" checked />
  <label>Two</label><input type="radio" class="second" name="something" />
  <div class="added"> HELLO </div>
</div>
```